# How can I read SQLite Databases?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Found more than 10 tutorials to "cursors" but I can't understand that.
My question is: How can I read data from a database?

For example:
Database name: Test_Database
Table name: tbl_users
In it are two columns: id, user_name

Now I like to read the user_name with id 3
==> SELECT user_name FROM tbl_useres WHERE id = 3

How can I give that out to a TextView, Toast or Alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this (at least my opinion ) is to create your custom `SqliteDatabaseHelper` and you can create a function like this :

```
public Cursor executeSQLQuery(String query){
    Cursor c = sqliteDb.rawQuery(query,null); // private static  SQLiteDatabase sqliteDb; 
    return c;
}
```

which returns `Cursor` and after that you can use this cursor like :

```
CustomDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new CustomDatabaseHelper(params...);
String sql = "SELECT name FROM cards WHERE id=2";
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql);
if(cursor.getCount()==0){
  // do something when you don't have any data, show message or something like this
} else if(cursor.getCount()>0){
    for(cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()){
       String getName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    }
}
```

This is at least how I'm using `Cursor` to get data from Database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok I'll try that tomorrow. lol
Android is so much heavier than PHP xD

Answer (score 0):

One way is, with the help of SQLLiteOpenHelper, first you need to obtain reference to your database. Then make a query OR rawQuery on your database. While using rawQuery you can directly post the query you typed in question directly. If you use query, you will use android built in API to construct to create the same query. Here is sample example [using sqllite openhelper](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html).

The Cursor you are referring is a pointer to the data received by your query, iterating cursor will allow you to access each row representation of your database.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following links for detail and simple example of

- [Insert](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/how-to-insert-data-in-to-a-sqlite-database-in-android/)
- [Retrieve](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-retrieve-data-from-a-sqlite-database-in-android/)
- [Update and Delete](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/how-to-update-and-delete-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android/)

data in a SQLite database in Android

Comment: Thanks Anuja. Insert, update and delete is no problem. I just didn't understand how it works with cursors. But now I know it.